# Laravel routing - shorten the urls upto only one URI segment

Tags: laravel-5

I have following urls:

1.Need to change From:

```
localhost/laravel/page/about-us/
```

to

```
localhost/laravel/about-us/
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Routing is one of the primary functionalities of the Framework, if you can't use it properly by yourself I suggest you to [read the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing).

I think the first example is explicit enough:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

This `Route` catches all of the requests that are sent to the `/` url (the base url)

So, you should have a look at your `\App\Http\routes.php` file and replace the line that starts with :

```
Route::get('page/about-us', function() ...
```

With:

```
Route::get('about-us', function() ...
```

And since you seem to be using xampp or other easyphp friends, you should probably rename your base directory from laravel to laravelproj if you want it to be available from `http://localhost/laravelproj` instead of `http://localhost/laravel`.

Defining [the default .htaccess file](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation#pretty-urls) should also help:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If this doesn't answer your question, I think you need to be more explicit.